# What thread is initializing static fields?

Tags: java

What thread is initializing static fields and static blocks? From my experiments I conclude that it is the same as the "calling" thread, i.e.

```
class Foo {
    static {
        System.err.printf("static {}:   %s\n", Thread.currentThread());
    }
}

public class Mini_StaticInitialization {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.err.printf("main:        %s\n", Thread.currentThread());
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
main:        Thread[main,5,main]
static {}:   Thread[main,5,main]
```

Are there any restrictions or is this always the case?

Comment: Your app is single-threaded.  It's execution all occurs within that same, single thread.  So what do you mean, "What thread...?"  There is only one thread for your application shown above.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why would you care which thread executes the static block?

Comment: @scottb This is a testcase to formulate my question, obviously this is not my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Usually* the static fields are initialized in the thread that first initializes the class, but I don't think that is specified in the JLS.

That's *usually* also the same thread that loads the class, but not necessarily.

The most relevant part of the JLS is probably [12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2):

> Because the Java programming language is multithreaded, initialization of a class or interface requires careful synchronization, since some other thread may be trying to initialize the same class or interface at the same time.

This *implies* (but does not state or require) that initialization happens in the thread that caused the class to require initialization.

Answer (score 2):

The static block is run when the class is loaded. I would assume that this is always the thread that is causing the class to load. This may be a different thread if the class is referenced in some way, even when you don't create an instance of Foo.

Comment: Strictly speaking that happens on class initialization and not on class loading. Most of the time those two happen at pretty much the same time, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

Code in static blocks is executed at class load time and it is done only once, no matter how many instance of the class you create. In your program main thread in the calling thread and your program runs in the same thread. If you try to execute new Foo() in a different thread also you will see the same output as static intialization occurs in the calling thread only.

Answer (score 0):

It is the thread that first loaded Foo will initialize static fields / run static blocks. If Foo was already loaded by another thread then Thread[main,5,main] would not touch them. Static initialization is done once.